# How do I find the values of a for which $f(x) = 3x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2(a-2) + a^2 -12ax$ does not intersect the x axis, assuming a > 1?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Spoiler alert: The answer is $a > \sqrt{14} + 3$

When $a>1$ there is only one stationary point.
I have access to a CAS calculator but still don't know how to solve this. Can anyone help?

The source is question 1) h) iii) from https://www.vcaa.vic.edu.au/Documents/exams/mathematics/2018/2018MM2-w.pdf

Comment: Because there is only $1$ stationary point, this stationary point must be above the x-axis for the function to have no roots. This is because both ends of the function tend to positive infinity.

Comment: The (smallest, I guess) $a$ will give a double root, meaning a sort of parabola tangent to the axis. When that happens, $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ have a common root, which can be detected by the polynomial gcd of the two. Find $f(x) = f'(x) q(x) + r(x) $ and then find when the remainder vanishes

Answer (score 0):

The method for doing this is to find the minimum value in terms of $a$, and making it greater than 0

$$f'(x) = 12x^3 + 12x^2 + 12x(a-2) -12a = 0$$

$$\implies f'(x) = 12(x^3+x^2+(a-2)x-a) =12( x(x+2)(x-1) + a(x-1))$$

$$\implies f'(x) = 12(x-1)((x^2 + 2x + a)$$

Now the minimum value will occur at $x=1$ for $a>1$, using $f''$ test at $x=1$

$$f(1) = a^2 - 6a -5$$

Can you proceed using the quadratic formula?

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$f’(x) =12(x-1)(x^2+2x+a)$$

For $a>0$, the minimum is at $x=1$. Then, with no interaction with the $x$-axis

$$f(1)= a^2-6a-5>0$$

which leads to

$$a>3+\sqrt{14}$$

Comment: $f(1) = a^2 - 6a-5$

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=12 x^3+12 x^2+12 (a-2) x-12 a=12 (x-1) \left(x^2+2 x+a\right)$

as $a>1$ the factor $x^2+2x+a$ is never zero because the discriminant $4-4a<0$

Thus the function has only one extreme $x=1$ which is a minimum because $f''(x)=12 a+36 x^2+24 x-24$ is positive at $x=1$.

Let's see for what value of $a$ the function intersects the $x$-axis
$$f(1)=a^2-6 a-5=0\to a = \sqrt{14}+3$$
Therefore for $a>\sqrt{14}+3$ the graph of $f(x)$ doesn't intersect the $x$-axis.